# Будет ли тег "нытьё" фирменной "изюминкой" русского SO?

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё, мета-метки

... или его потом удалят как неформат?

[нытье](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5)
[нытьё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91)

Comment: Полагаю, @Athari скажет, что SO не для нытья.

Comment: Опишите тэг `нытьё` для начала, что бы было понятно о чем речь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/1274

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что все с переходом на SO набрали полные баулы серьезности, в которой запрещено любое неописанное в вики действие. Мне тоже хочется, чтобы это все выглядело как можно красивей, и чтобы ссылки на мои блестящие ответы распространялись интернет-курьерами во все концы сети, но, может, как-нибудь без введения драконовских правил и педантичного следования вики? Оно само образуется, если это нужно. Если почитаете Этвуда, то он, в общем-то, сторонник естественной эволюции.

Comment: @skywinder: описали )

Comment: @NickVolynkin отлично! :)

Answer (score 13):

Надо спросить у @knes - он создал этот тег и он так долго и тщательно его продвигал ))

Если говорить по существу, то пусть будет. Русский SO отличается от большого SO прежде всего своим человеческим измерением, так что нехай будет.

Comment: Человеческое измерение — это шестое что ли, как чувство?

Answer (score 10):

> Надо спросить у @knes

Постоянно кто-то чем-то недоволен. Причем хочет высказаться не в мифической(на тот момент) мете, а здесь, сейчас и чтобы обязательно быть услышанным. Активное продвижение-таки имело место быть, так как хотел предложить при помощи тега сделать мостик между метой и основным форумом. То есть, посты в хэшкоде отмеченные тегом "нытье" автоматически появляются в мете с тегом хэшкод. Но развитие форума круто сменило курс, так что будут ли актуальны подобные запросы - не знаю.

Будет ли фирменной изюминкой или будет стерт решит сообщество, как обычно) Если останется, буду стараться так же его продвигать в подобных постах, так как без нытья, увы, не обойдется, а тег позволит людям, которые нытье не выносят, внести это безобразие в черный список.

Comment: Но на meta.ru.SO, думаю, этот тег в любом случае останется.

Comment: «Решит сообщество, как обычно» :) Какими наивными мы все были в 2015 году!

Comment: Воу-воу!!! какие люди. *пригладил седую бороду*

Answer (score 6):

Да, будет. У него теперь есть описание, это ставит его в один ряд с burninate-request. Осталось маскота придумать.

> Вопросы, в которых участники обращаются к сообществу за эмоциональной поддержкой и воодушевлением перед лицом всех трудностей, связанных с участием в работе Stack Overflow на русском языке. Используйте эту метку только для собственных вопросов. Отмечать чужой вопрос этой меткой нежелательно. Оставьте пользователю возможность самостоятельно привнести нотку самоиронии.

Answer (score 5):

Нужно больше бессмысленных и беспощадных метамемометок для развлечения:
[кодостена](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0)[нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91)[помогите](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5)[лаба](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0)[тлен](/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd)[крестопроблемы](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b)[костыль](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bb%d1%8c)[индусы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b)[вебмакаки](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8)[плюсанул](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb)[паника](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)[яннп](/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%bf)[проэкт](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%82)

Comment: Я бы поддержал [tag:лаба], [tag:крестопроблемы] и [tag:яннп]

Comment: Да эти три метки четко характеризуют ситуацию.

Comment: Вопрос медленно превращается в каламбур :\

Comment: Из приведённых не нужны: "помогите", "тлен", "индусы" (дубль "костыля"), "плюсанул", "паника", "проэкт", "яннп". Могут иметь смысл: "кодостена" (чтобы не заходить в соответствующий вопрос в отсутствие настроения копаться в коде), "нытьё" (чтобы сопоставлять своё настроение и вопрос), "лаба" (аналог тега "homework"), "крестопроблемы" (уточнение тега "c++" для любителей поломать голову над полотном ошибки от компилятора), "костыль" (аналог тега "hack"). В целом мне многие мета-теги не мешают, я бы их в SO удалял более переборчиво.

Comment: ещё 'мистика', которую я безуспешно пытался продвинуть ещё на хэшкоде

Answer (score 3):

А как насчёт вопросов "Я не хочу читать документацию в пару строк, пусть за меня всё напишут на SO". Ибо сайт превращается из "тут я могу найти ответ на сложный вопрос" в "решение домашних заданий для 6-11 классов"

Comment: Четыре года уже превращается, да пока не превратился.

Comment: А по сабжу - замораживать и при отсутствии положительной динамики - вычищать.

Comment: Мне кажется, это не связано с "нытьём". Про домашние задания есть относительно официальный guideline (на большом SO). Про политику насчёт "send-me-the-codez" ("напишите за меня прорамму") тоже. Первое можно (но осторожно), второе нельзя. Ранее был тег "homework".

Answer (score 2):

Пусть будет. Я его воспринял как тег для общих, языконезависимых вопросов по выяснению истины, такие вопросы пару раз появлялись.

Comment: Думаю, сразу бежать править мою историю было не лучшей идеей.

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема состоит в том, чтобы чётко определить круг вопросов, которые можно было бы отметить таким тегом, но которые при этом были бы релевантны тематике сайта, то я бы отнёс к данной категории следующий тип вопросов. Иногда бывает, что у задающего вопрос уже есть решение его проблемы. Однако оно его по каким-то причинам не устраивает. Ему хочется чего-то большего. Например, он знает, как сделать что-то на своём любимом языке. Но недавно он где-то увидел решение той же проблемы на другом языке, которое ему очень понравилось. И вот теперь ему интересно, можно ли сделать так же хорошо на его языке.